# Extract dependencies and versions from a gradle file with Python

Tags: python, parsing, gradle

I need to extract the dependencies and versions of build.gradle file. I do not have access to the project folder, only to the file, so this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465981/python-script-to-out-put-dependencies-of-build-gradle-file) does not work in my case. I am using python to do the parsing, but it has not worked for me, especially since it does not have a structure already defined for example JSON.

I'm using these files to test my parsing:

- [Twidere gradle](https://github.com/TwidereProject/Twidere-Android/blob/master/build.gradle)
- [votling grade](https://github.com/sergiocasero/votlin-app/blob/master/build.gradle)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do what you want.

As you can see from the answer given to the SO post you linked, a gradle build file is a script. That script is written in either Kotlin or Groovy, and you can programmatically define the version and dependencies in a multitude of ways. For instance, to set a version, you can hard code it in the script, reference a system property, or get it through an included plugin and more. In your first example, it is set through an extension property, and in the second it is not even defined - likely leaving it up to the individual sub-projects if they even use it. In both examples, the build files are just a small part of a larger multi-project, and each individual project potentially has their own defined dependencies and version.

So there is really no way to tell without actually *evaluating* the script. And you can't do that unless you have access to the full project structure.